# Kubernetes bridging between VM host network and Cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I'm pretty new to Kubernetes and was exploring Services to try and access my application running inside a MiniKube. This just a default HTTP server that responds with Hello World.

Now I know about the Minikube command to get a bridge to my application but I was trying to replicate this myself by using Services and Endpoints to no avail.

Below are my configuration files that I used and some info about the networks, this is just for a local test environment and I don't have access to any cloud providers. I would just like to be able to go to 192.168.99.1 and connect

**vboxnet0**: 192.168.99.x/24

**hello-node-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-node
  labels:
    app: hello-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-node
        image: gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**hello-node-serviceport.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: http-service-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello-node
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
  externalIPs: ["192.168.99.180"]
```

**hello-node-endpoint.yaml**

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: http-service-nodeport
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.99.180
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the issue might be related rather with your **VirtualBox** network settings than anything related to **Kubernetes** or **Minikube**.

What are your **VBox** networking settings ? Do you use bridged adapter or host only adapter ? Or maybe you're using **NAT** ? And what's the address `192.168.99.1` ? So you're trying to connect to `192.168.99.1`, not to `192.168.99.180` ?

I assume you're trying to access your cluster from host system, right ? If so, you need to consider using **bridged adapter** or **host only adapter** as only those two networking modes enable access from host to guest. Please refer to [this](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox) article.